# Program terminated with signal sigsegv, segmentation fault. #0 0x000000000040199e in ?? ()

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I am a beginner for opencv. Yesterday I wrote a simple code in c++, which is really puzzled me. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
void cvtColor_cv()
{
    Mat image;
    Mat image2;
    image=imread("/home/shz/alltest/c++/640.jpg",1);
    namedWindow("Display Image",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Display Image2",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display Image",image);
    cvtColor(image,image2,COLOR_BGR2Luv);
    imshow("Display Image2",image2);
    waitKey(0);
}
void cvtColor_cal()
{
    Mat image;
    Mat image2;
    double a[3][3];
    image=imread("/home/shz/alltest/c++/640.jpg",1);
    int height=image.rows;
    int width=image.cols;
    cout << height <<endl;
    cout << width <<endl;
    //Vec3b bgr=image.at<Vec3b>(0,0);
    cout << image.at<Vec3b>(0,0)[0] << endl;
    
    //namedWindow("Display Image",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    //namedWindow("Display Image2",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    //imshow("Display Image",image);
    for (int i=1;i<height;i++)
    {
        for (int j=1;j<width;j++)
        {   
            
            //cout << (int) data[j] <<endl;
            //Vec3b bgr=image.at<Vec3b>(i,j);
            cout << image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] <<endl;
                
        }
    }       
    //image=1/0.17697*a*image;
    //imshow("Display Image2",image);
    
    waitKey(0);
}
int main()
{
    cvtColor_cal();
    return 0;
}
```

As we can see ,the output is：

```
746
1080
�
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

After I use GDB to debug this program and it prompts me：

```
program terminated with signal sigsegv, segmentation fault. #0 0x000000000040199e in ?? ()
```

Obviously, image.rows and image.cols worked well. `im.at<Vec3b>(0,0)[0]` also worked but the output is a little strange.The for loops that I have tested can work well done(I used it to output a lot number "1").

But when I write `im.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]` into for loops.  It has reported the above error.

This is really a hard question for me. The version of OpencV I use is 4.5.5. The version of gcc I use is 5.4.0.

The GDB result is here:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/shz/alltest/test_2022.4.9/Display 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
746
1080
�

Breakpoint 1, cvtColor_cal () at Display.cpp:49
49              Vec3b bgr=image.at<Vec3b>(i,j);
(gdb) n

Breakpoint 2, cv::Matx<unsigned char, 3, 1>::Matx (this=0x7fffffffe4b0, 
    values=0x3fd51eb851eb91ca <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x3fd51eb851eb91ca>) at /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp:673
673     for( int i = 0; i < channels; i++ ) val[i] = values[i];
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401a58 in cv::Matx<unsigned char, 3, 1>::Matx (
    this=0x7fffffffe4b0, 
    values=0x3fd51eb851eb91ca <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x3fd51eb851eb91ca>) at /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp:673
673     for( int i = 0; i < channels; i++ ) val[i] = values[i];
(gdb) n

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
```

```
47              
48              //cout << (int) data[j] <<endl;
49              Vec3b bgr=image.at<Vec3b>(i,j);
50              cout << image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] <<endl;
51                  
52          }
53      }       
54      //image=1/0.17697*a*image;
55      //imshow("Display Image2",image);
56
```

Comment: Q: This is the expression that's giving the segmentation violation, correct: `image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]`? Q: What happens when you restore `Vec3b bgr=image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)` and step through the debugger?  Is "bgr" alway valid, for all loop values of i and j?

Comment: Sorry,sir. My understanding of c++ is not very deep, so I will edit my question and put the results of debugger below.@paulsm4

Comment: So you're a beginner in C++ *AND* OpenCV, correct?  `Vec3b bgr=image.at<Vec3b>(x,y)` returns the pixel at the coordinates x and y.  It sounds like your x,y coordinates might, at a certain point in your loops, be *WRONG*. Hence the crash.  Q: Maybe you accidentally got "i" (0..height) and "j" (0..width) backwards?  Maybe you should actually use `image.at<Vec3b>(j,i)` instead of `image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,sir. I have used Opencv in python some times, which is much easier than c++. I must admit that there are many differences between c++ and python. In fact, I have tried using `image.at<Vec3b>(j,i)`, but got the same error.  Just now I found that there may be something wrong with `<Vec3b>` since `cout << image.at<Vec3b>(0,0)[4]<<endl;` can also output `�`. Since the pixel matrix of the color map does not have a fifth channel at all, I wonder if there is something wrong here?@paulsm4

Comment: Note: when you type `im.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]` into paragraph text, the angle brackets disappear, because the editor thinks it is HTML. This is the purpose of the preview pane - so you can check your post is correct before you post. The solution is to use inline formatting, as I have done here.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're familiar with using your debugger (gdb), how to set breakpoints, and how to single-step through the code: that's good.
2. You're able to see exactly where the segmentation violation is occurring - that's good, too:

   ```
   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
   0x0000000000401a58 in cv::Matx<unsigned char, 3, 1>::Matx (
       this=0x7fffffffe4b0, 
      values=0x3fd51eb851eb91ca <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x3fd51eb851eb91ca>) at /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp:673
   ```
3. Line 673 in matx.hpp is inside OpenCV.  We need to know the line in *YOUR code* that's *CAUSING* OpenCV to crash. I suspect it might be here:

   ```
   for (int i=1;i<height;i++) {
     for (int j=1;j<width;j++) {    
       cout << image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] << endl; // <-- I suspect "i" and/or "j" might be incorrect
   ```
4. SUGGESTION: instrument your code like this:

   ```
   std::cout << std::unitbuf; // enable automatic flushing
   for (int y=1;y<height;y++) {
     for (int x=1;x<width;x++) {    
       cout << "x=" << x << ", y=" << y << ": " << image.at<Vec3b>(x,y)[0] << endl;
   ```

   - I changed the variables "i" and "j" to "y" and "x", and ensured they corresponded to the "vertical" and "horizontal" dimensions, respectively.
   - I print out *each* iteration for *each* pixel (the *last* x/y printed out before crashing is likely the culprit).
   - I added a [unitbuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/unitbuf) manipulator to ensure the line that crashes actually prints out.

I hope this will help you troubleshoot *WHERE* ... and consequently *WHY* your app is crashing.

Comment: Thank you again for your generous help, sir. I change my code like wthat you suggested. It seems like the crashing happened right where it started. Because it doesn't output any pixel values. The output is as same as before :`746
1080
�
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Comment: Maybe the problem is occurring before your loop?  You need to figure our which line of your code is causing the problem, and work backwards from there.  SUGGESTION: Run your program in gdb.  When it crashes, run [bt](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html).   Copy/paste the stack trace ([Edit] your original question, add the stack trace).

Comment: It seems so. I'll try to find it, thank you for your selfless help these days.Good luck for you, sir@paulsm4

Comment: @hai shi - please update your current status